# What version of WoD is this?

Tags: world-of-darkness, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, product-identification

I've found recently a few official freebie starter kits to various old World of Darkness settings [available here for example](https://web.archive.org/web/20160630040150/http://gamingnerdsrus.co/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=1f4b988029157317f5e75ec7ae36a41d&action=downloads;cat=31). While the general settings are the same to the one I know from (which i believe is 2nd edition), this ones have completely different, simplified mechanic based on D6 instead of D10 and greatly simplifying some rules to the point of absurd(i.e. if Arhoun Get gets on start +2 dices in attack!). What version is this?

Comment: Yup — those are the **Introductory Kits**.

Answer (score 11):

All but "Geist the Sin-Eaters" belong to the classic World of Darkness.

I think that was in the revised era when White Wolf launched those starter kits. They are not a previous version of the rules. They are small games with very simple rules and the same setting of the core books.

The aim was to attract people to the game universes with a simpler set of rules and a summarized explanation of the setting. Expecting that, if the players like the game, they would jump to the serious full core games.

Comment: Like Magic's "Portal" sets. Eventually they all realised it was a silly idea.

Comment: @Lohoris Actually, I have seen the free starter kits used by many modern RPGs. Even Mage 20 had one this year. Maybe the only difference is that the rules do not change so much.

Comment: @Flamma and that's a vital difference. The "silly idea" I was talking about was the rule difference and such, if they are just a subset of the rules, that's fine and makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

### World of Darkness

There were multiple generations of [**Introductory Kits & Quickstarts**](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Quickstarts): in or around 1997, which is smack dab **2nd Edition**, and the early 2000s, which is **Revised Edition**, and the late 2010s, which is 20th-anniversary Edition. As examples:

- 1997 [Changeling the Dreaming Introductory Kit for 2nd Edition](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Changeling:_The_Dreaming_Introductory_Kit)
- 1997 [Vampire the Masquerade Introductory Kit for 2nd Edition](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Vampire:_The_Masquerade_Introductory_Kit)
- 2001 for [Werewolf the Apocalypse Free Introductory Kit for Revised Edition](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Werewolf:_The_Apocalypse_Free_Introductory_Kit)
- 2001 for [Mage the Ascension **Quickstart** for Revised Edition](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension_Revised_Edition_Quickstart)
- 2014 for [Mage the Ascension 20th Anniversary Edition Quickstart](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Mage:_The_Ascension_20th_Anniversary_Edition_Quickstart)
- 2017 for [Changeling the Dreaming 20th Anniversary Edition Quickstart](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Yours_to_Keep:_A_Changeling:_The_Dreaming_20th_Anniversary_Edition_Jumpstart)

### Chronicles of Darkness

The first edition of Chronicles of darkness had its own Quickstart packs, starting shortly after the 2004 reboot as "new World of Darkness"

- 2004 for [Vampire the Requiem](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Danse_de_la_Morte)
- 2005 for [Werewolf the Forsaken](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Manitou_Springs)
- 2005 for [Mage the Awakening](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Gloria_Mundi) which is a whole campaign
- 2007 for [Changeling the Lost Quickstart](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Changeling:_The_Lost_Quickstart)
- 2008 for [Hunter the Vigil](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Hunter:_The_Vigil_Quickstart_%E2%80%94_One_Year_Later) & [Hunter the Vigil](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Hunter:_The_Vigil_Quickstart_%E2%80%94_The_Hunt)
- 2009 for [Geist the Sin Eater](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Geist:_The_Sin-Eaters_Quickstart)

Since 2019, the 2nd Edition of Chronicles of Darkness started with its own Quickstarts, such as [Hearts on Trial: Changeling The Lost 2nd Edition Jumpstart](https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/Hearts_on_Trial:_Changeling_The_Lost_2nd_Edition_Jumpstart)